# Cocos2d - Is is possible to turn off collision for a Box2d b2Body with a b2FixtureDef?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision

I have a b2Body with a b2FixtureDef.  I'd like to be able to turn off the ability of the b2Body to collide.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Make it sensor.

```
    b2FixtureDef fd;
    fd.isSensor = true;
    body->CreateFixture(&fd);
```

Also with filter(fd.filter) you can specify collision specific to body.